# How to get id from mysql database for just inputted form data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I understand the `lastInsertId` or `mysqli_insert_id` function returns the last inserted id of the insert or update query but say you had two intending users filling out a form in different locations at the same time and user2's id was the last at the time the `mysqli_insert_id`  on user1's script was being run instead of user1's id. 
will the id returned be user2's id or user1's id? I know the script will run in micro or milliseconds and its possible the scenario might not ever occur but is it possible that the returned id in a case where two intending users post form data at the same time can be different from the actual id that should be returned. 
I hope the question is pretty clear. I am also very new to programming so pardon me.
I would also like to thank all the contributors on stack exchange, I have learnt alot in a very short while.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to worry about here.

They all call [the underlying MySQL functionality](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/getting-unique-id.html).

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz. really helped me clarify things.

Comment: @MrMarho Glad I could help, and good work considering race conditions. Lots of people don't take the care to consider such things.

Answer (score -1):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID().

It will get you the latest row inserted in a table i.e the last row for you.